# How do I turn JSON Objects into a dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Working on a freshwater fish conservation project. I scraped a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "fish": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "n": "NO INFORMATION",
      "a": "NONE",
      "i": "none.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "n": "Hampala barb",
      "a": "Hampala macrolepidota",
      "i": "hampala.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "n": "Giant snakehead",
      "a": "Channa micropeltes",
      "i": "toman.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "n": "Clown featherback",
      "a": "Chitala ornata",
      "i": "belida.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm trying to extract the keys `"id"` and `"a"` into a python dictionary like this:

```
fish_id = {
  0 : "NONE",
  1 : "Hampala macrolepidota",
  2 : "Channa micropeltes",
  3 : "Chitala ornata"
}
```

Comment: Understood. Will not do this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json

data = """{
  "fish": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "n": "NO INFORMATION",
      "a": "NONE",
      "i": "none.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "n": "Hampala barb",
      "a": "Hampala macrolepidota",
      "i": "hampala.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "n": "Giant snakehead",
      "a": "Channa micropeltes",
      "i": "toman.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "n": "Clown featherback",
      "a": "Chitala ornata",
      "i": "belida.png"
    }
  ]
}"""

data_dict = json.loads(data)
fish_id = {}
for item in data_dict["fish"]:
    fish_id[item["id"]] = item["a"]

print(fish_id)
```

Comment: well done. This code should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First create a fish.json file and get your JSON file;

```
with open('fish.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Then, take your fishes;

```
fish1 = data['fish'][0]
fish2 = data['fish'][1]
fish3 = data['fish'][2]
fish4 = data['fish'][3]
```

After that take only values for each, because you want to create a dictionary only from values;

```
value_list1=list(fish1.values())
value_list2=list(fish2.values())
value_list3=list(fish3.values())
value_list4=list(fish4.values())
```

Finally, create fish_id dictionary;

```
fish_id = {
    f"{value_list1[0]}" : f"{value_list1[2]}",
    f"{value_list2[0]}" : f"{value_list2[2]}",
    f"{value_list3[0]}" : f"{value_list3[2]}",
    f"{value_list4[0]}" : f"{value_list4[2]}",
}
```

if you run;

```
print(fish_id)
```

Result will be like below, but if you can use for loops, it can be more effective.

{'0': 'NONE', '1': 'Hampala macrolepidota', '2': 'Channa micropeltes', '3': 'Chitala ornata'}